# Push table data from django postgres model to remote oracle database

Tags: python, django, oracle, postgresql

Hey guys i have a problem. There is an application that i built using django and it runs on postgresql. The application works perfectly but until recently , i was asked to push particular table data in the models of the django application to a remote oracle database. For example i have a model that looks like this:

```
 class SimRegistrationForm(models.Model):
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField('Mobile Number',max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    alternative_number = models.IntegerField('Alternative Number',max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField('Date', blank=False, null=False)
    honorifics = models.CharField('Honorific', max_length=10, choices=HONORIFIC, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name',max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField('Middle Name',max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name',max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth', blank=False, null=False)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
```

I have asked this question before on this forum but have not had as much help with very little response. How can i be able to achieve this ? I know django supports multiple database connections basing on what i have read here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/
I would like such that it pushes some of the table data to the remote oracle database in realtime and data should also remain on the postgres database too. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to replicate the data from postgresql to oracle for some particular model.

MultiDB is not conceived for replication, but with a recent version of Django you can be able to pull this stunt.

Configure Django with two databases, the postgresql as default and the oracle as a second database. Lets say you called the second database database "orcl":

1. create the same table you want to replicate in the oracle database
2. write a custom "save" method in the Django model that calls the `super()` "save" method and also `super(YourModel, self).save(using='orcl')`

Should be something like this (untested):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    kwargs.update({'using' : 'orcl'})
    super(YourModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[update]

> comment from OP: But now the problem is i dont want to send all the data of the table to the remote database. I just want to send some columns to the remote database. Is it possible to achieve this with a similar method

I think it is possible. Keeping the same pk on both databases will make your life easier:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    remote = OtherModel(
        id = self.id,
        some_field = self.some_field,
        another_field = self.another_field,
    )
    remote.save(using='orcl')
```

Let me know if this works. You have to either 1) define the OtherModel and create the corresponding table in the remote database or 2) create the remote table and use `manage.py inspectdb` to create the model.

Comment: But now the problem is i  dont want to send all the data of the table to the remote database. I just want to send some columns to the remote database. Is it possible to achieve this with a similar method.

Comment: answer updated (remember you have to define the OtherModel and create its table on the remote database)

Comment: yes have seen the update. but can i send only certain columns to the remote database like lets say, date, honorifics, firstname, lastname

Comment: OtherModel is supposed to have just the column subset you want to send to the remote database. Just occurred to me that my solution is not handling deletes, for that you will can use the [post_delete signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete).

Comment: Ohhh... ok... cool. Will give it a go. So basically i create a new model with the columns i want to send to the remote database. Will it be in realtime and not require double entry of data? i mean if they enter the data in the original model , it should also be automagically written in the othermodel columns...

Comment: Pretty much, updates will be handled gracefully. If you want to handle  deletes as well, use the [post_delete signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete).

Answer (score 1):

Use a database replication tool of some sort. Since it's two different databases your options aren't very many. I'm only aware of [Oracle's GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html), and I don't know if it's any good.

If you don't need to sync the data very often, you can probably roll your own script that dumps, transforms and loads the data, say every night or so.

Comment: Yeah seems i will have to write my own script that will dump the data and loads it into the oracle db..